# Capture output of autograded answer for subsequent autograder tests in nbgrader

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub, nbgrader

I am trying to automate `autograding` with `nbgrader`. Usually the student writes a piece of code (like a `variable` or a `function`) in the `autograded answer` cell that the instructor uses (by referring to the `variable` or `function`) to write `autograder tests`.

But some times the input code from the `autograded answer` cell can be just a `print(...)` which outputs something to the screen (rather than a `variable` or `function`). In that case how is it possible to ***capture*** the printed output so that we can use it the next cell for writing `autograder tests` on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nbgrader docs [include an example](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/autograding_resources.html?highlight=print#id3) demonstrating how to patch the builtin function `print` so you can capture and test printed output:

> Problem: verify that a function call results in the printing of a certain result
>
> ```py
> def foo()
>     #...
>     print('right result')
> ```
>
> The test code for this can be written as
>
> ```py
> from unittest.mock import patch
> with patch('__main__.print') as mock_print:
>     foo()
>
> mock_print.assert_called_once_with('right_result')
> ```
>
> This test passes silently if the print is correct, but if the print is wrong:
>
> ```py
> def foo()
>     #...
>     print('wrong result')
> ```
>
> an assertion error is raised with output of the form
>
> ```py
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> ...
>
> AssertionError: Expected call: print('right result')
> Actual call: print('wrong result')
> ```